# JAVASCRIPT decode a base64string (which is an encoded zipfile) to a zipfile and get the zipfiles content by name

Tags: javascript, json, binary, base64, zip

the question says it all, im receiving a base64 encoded ZIPFILE from the server, which I first want to decode to a ZIPFILE in memory and then get the ZIPFILES content, which is a json-file.

I tried to use JSZIP but im totally lost in this case ... the base64 string is received with javascript by a promise.

So my question in short is: How can I convert a base64 encoded ZIPFILE to a ZIPFILE in memory to get its contents.

BASE64 -> ZIPFILE -> CONTENT

I use this complicated process to save much space on my database. And I dont want to handle this process on server-side, but on clientside with JS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is interested in my solution to this problem read my answer right here:

I received the data in a base64-string format, then converted the string to a blob. Then I used the blob-handle to load the zipfile with the JSZip-Library. After that I could just grab the contents of the zipfile. Code is below:

```
function base64ToBlob(base64) {
    let binaryString =  window.atob(base64);
    let binaryLen = binaryString.length;

    let ab = new ArrayBuffer(binaryLen);
    let ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (let i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
       ia[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    let bb = new Blob([ab]);
    bb.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    bb.name = "archive.zip";
    bb.type = "zip";

    return bb;
}
```

To get the contents of the zipfile:

```
            let blob = base64ToBlob(resolved);
            let zip = new JSZip();
            zip.loadAsync(blob).then(function(zip) {
                zip.file("archived.json").async("string").then(function (content) {
                   console.log(content);
                   // content is the file as a string
                });
            }).catch((e) => {

            });
```

As you can see, first the blob is created from the base64-string. Then the handle is given over to the JSZip loadAsync method. After that you have to set the name of the file which you want to retrieve from the zipfile. In this case it is the file called "archived.json". Now because of the async("string") function the file (file contents) are returned as a string. To further use the extracted string, just work with the content variable.